# Validity of XML against Amazon MWS's Inventory/Price feed XSDs

Tags: xml, xsd, amazon-mws, price, amazon-product-api

I am trying to change the price of an item using Amazon's MWS API for a product on Amazon France.

The XML I am sending up is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>ABC123</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Price>
            <SKU>11</SKU> 
            <StandardPrice currency="EUR">312.25</StandardPrice>
            <MinimumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">299.75</MinimumSellerAllowedPrice>               
            <MaximumSellerAllowedPrice currency="EUR">343.38</MaximumSellerAllowedPrice>
        </Price>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

But Amazon is rejecting the XML saying that the currency field contains an invalid value:

```
...
            <Result>
                <MessageID>0</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>90215</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>100% of the products in your file did not process successfully. We recommend using Check My File to help you identify and correct common listing errors before updating your inventory. To use Check My File, upload your file on the &quot;Add Products via Upload&quot; page in the &quot;Check My File&quot; section.</ResultDescription>
            </Result>
            <Result>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
                <ResultMessageCode>90057</ResultMessageCode>
                <ResultDescription>The Message/Price/StandardPrice/@currency field contains an invalid value: EUR. To correct this error, choose from the valid set of values.</ResultDescription>
                <AdditionalInfo>
                    <SKU>14</SKU>
                </AdditionalInfo>
            </Result>
...
```

I have downloaded their XSDs, merged them into one and, together with the XML, used this website to validate the XML: [xml-validator-xsd](https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html)

All good? Nope. Despite the website saying that the XML is valid against the XSD, Amazon still rejects the XML.

So, I broke down the XSD...

The Price element from Price.XSD:

```
<xsd:element name="Price">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ref="SKU"/>
            <xsd:element name="StandardPrice" type="OverrideCurrencyAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
            ...
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

And from amzn-base.XSD, OverrideCurrencyAmount is defined as

```
<xsd:complexType name="OverrideCurrencyAmount">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="CurrencyAmountWithDefault">
            <xsd:attribute name="zero" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

CurrencyAmountWithDefault is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="CurrencyAmountWithDefault">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="BasePriceCurrencyAmount">
            <xsd:attribute name="currency" type="BaseCurrencyCodeWithDefault" use="required"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And BasePriceCurrencyAmount and BaseCurrencyCodeWithDefault are:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="BasePriceCurrencyAmount">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:totalDigits value="20"/>
        <xsd:fractionDigits value="4" fixed="true"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="BaseCurrencyCodeWithDefault">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="USD"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="GBP"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="EUR"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="JPY"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="CAD"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="CNY"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="INR"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="AUD"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="BRL"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="MXN"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="TRY"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="DEFAULT"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="AED"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="SAR"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="SGD"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="SEK"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="PLN"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="EGP"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

EUR is valid value according to their XSD. Am I missing something?

UPDATE: 2020-12-16

OxygenXML also states that my XML is valid against the XSDs downloaded from Amazon seller central. And if I change the value EUR to eg ABC123, it rejects the XML as expected saying that ABC123 is an unexpected value.

Comment: Sounds as if you have done the 'due diligence'. However, merging multiple XSDs into a single XSD can sometimes change the meaning. Check out 'chameleon namespaces'.

Comment: @kimbert: Comment much appreciated, thank you.  And that Chameleon thingy sounds interesting. Will check it out and update when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  XML is correct and validates against the XSD.

However, the problem is that the marketplace Id in the request was not being set to eg an EU markplace code. In my original post, the default marketplace was UK (ie GBP) and thus any attempt to use another currency code was being rejected.

Solution is to simply set the marketplace Id when building up the request.

eg:

```
...
// https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_Endpoints.html
string franceMarketplaceId = "A13V1IB3VIYZZH";
...
myAmazonSubmitFeedRequest.MarketplaceIdList.Id.Add(franceMarketplaceId );
...
```

Do this and then Amazon MWS will recognised that the price feed is for the specified marketplace and validate the currency accordingly.